# Javascript array showing as empty but shows data after reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I am loading the data in to state initialPetData like this:

```
                useEffect(() => {
                    setShowButton(true);
                    fetch("http://localhost:8080/upload/recieve", {
                        method: "GET",
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        },
                    })
                        .then((res) => res.json())
                        .then((data) => {
                            console.log(data);
                            setInitialPetData(data);
                            console.log("Initial Pet Data: ", initialPetData);

                            setEncodedImageData(data.imageSrc);
                        });
                }, []);
```

but on console log line it shows as empty, therefore the data cannot be rendered but if i make a change and save. It will reload pet data will show as filled here is a picture:

Before :
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM3Ms.png)

after saving:
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AnSk.png)

Comment: `setState` (or in your case `setInitalPetData`) isn't synchronous ...